# how to change permalinks from id to name of a particular location

Tags: permalinks

I am working on WordPress permalinks. I wanted to change the permalink URL from

`xyz.com/abc/locations/18` (which is location id)

to

`xyz.com/abc/locations/locationname`

With locationid the page is loading perfectly but when I change to locationname the page is giving a 404 error.

Comment: Is this a custom post type? Default Posts? How do you change it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have not set the permalinks correctly..

Delete your .htaccess file and try setting permalinks to postname
[image]